# Continuity problem (Theorem)

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Just out of curiosity, I have this question;

> Definition: A function f is continuous at a number a if limit of f(x) as x approaches a is equal to f(a).

Okay so:

Let p = if limit of f(x) as x approaches a is equal to f(a).
Let q =  A function f is continuous at a number a.

We know that p implies q, we don't know if q implies p.

So my question is, out of curiosity: why do we assume because functions such as polynomials (continuous everywhere) have to have their limits as x approaches a equal to a?

Comment: $p$ is equivalent to $q$ by definition.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is no if and only if. The definition is not clearly stating that p and q are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that in general, just because $p\rightarrow q$ doesn't mean that $q\rightarrow p$.

However, your statement regarding continuous functions is not a theorem, it is a definition. It is not just saying that a function for which the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is equal to $f(a)$ must be continuous at $a$.  It is defining what it means to be continuous at $a$.  Therefore, if a function doesn't meet that condition, then automatically it is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being confused because of the way this definition is worded. Mathematical definitions are always if and only if, even if they use the weaker word "if" in it. The definition SHOULD say:

> "A function $f$ is continuous at a number $a$ **if and only if** the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is equal to $f(a)$."

Note that this doesn't hold for non-definitions such as theorems, though! There, "if" really just means "*if*".